# What is this node "object Text" in a DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a html/JS file which have buttons to navigate the DOM tree and report information about the node currently being visited.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Example</title>
            <meta name="author" content="Adam Freeman"/>
            <meta name="description" content="A simple example"/>
            <style>
                pre {border: medium double black;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <pre id="results"></pre>
            <p id="tblock">
                There are lots of different kinds of fruit - there are over 500 varieties
                of <span id="banana">banana</span> alone. By the time we add the countless
                types of <span id="apple">apples</span>,
                <span="orange">oranges</span="orange">, and other well-known fruit, we are
                faced with thousands of choices. 
            </p>
            <p>
                One of the most interesting aspects of fruit is the variety available in
                each country. I live near London, in an area which is known for
                its apples.
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="parent">Parent</button>
                <button id="child">First Child</button>
                <button id="prev">Prev Sibling</button>
                <button id="next">Next Sibling</button>
            </p>
     
            <script>
                var resultsElem = document.getElementById("results");
                var element = document.body;
                
                var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
                for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                    buttons[i].onclick = handleButtonClick;
                }
                
                processNewElement(element);
    
                function handleButtonClick(e) {
                    if (element.style) {
                        element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    
                    if (e.target.id == "parent" && element != document.body) {
                        element = element.parentNode;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "child" && element.hasChildNodes()) {
                        element = element.firstChild;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "prev" && element.previousSibling) {
                        element = element.previousSibling;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "next" && element.nextSibling) {
                        element = element.nextSibling;
                    }
                    processNewElement(element);
                    if (element.style) {
                        element.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
                    }
                }
                
                function processNewElement(elem) {
                    resultsElem.innerHTML = "Element type: " + elem + "\n";
      resultsElem.innerHTML += "Element id: " + elem.id + "\n";
      resultsElem.innerHTML += "Element text content: " + elem.wholeText + "\n";
                    resultsElem.innerHTML += "Has child nodes: "
                        + elem.hasChildNodes() + "\n";
                    if (elem.previousSibling) {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += ("Prev sibling is: "
                             + elem.previousSibling + "\n");
                    } else {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "No prev sibling\n";
                    }
                    if (elem.nextSibling) {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "Next sibling is: "
                            + elem.nextSibling + "\n";
                    } else {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "No next sibling\n";
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When I first click button "parent" and then button "first child", it output is given at the end of the post.

What does the node "object Text" refer to? Does it represent the entire content of the `<body>` element?

Is the node "object Text" a `Text` node? Why `elem.wholeText` doesn't output any in "Element text content", given that the node is "object Text"?

[image]

Comment: [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) is a special type of node that represents just text. You can try running something like `document.body.appendChild(new Text('abc'))` and see the text appear as the very last text node in body. This happens when you have HTML that contains text between elements, like `<body>   <pre></pre></body>` — spaces form a Text node.

Comment: The `firstChild` of `body` is definitely a text node. It represents the carriage return whitespace after the tag.

Comment: maybe, using `JSON.stringify(elem.wholeText)` will help you see, what you're looking at

Comment: It is the white space that precedes the `<title>` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every part of a DOM Document is generically referred to as a "node", and [nodes come in different types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants). A Text node is not an element, but rather any part of the document that contains raw text.

Take the following. How many nodes do you see?

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

There are 2. The `p` element node and the text node within it as its `firstChild`. All nodes have a `nodeValue` property, but surprisingly, element nodes that contain text don't have a `nodeValue`, their actual value resides within the text node that is a child of the element node.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("p").nodeType);   // 1
console.log(document.querySelector("p").nodeValue);  // null
console.log(document.querySelector("p").firstChild.nodeType);  // 3
console.log(document.querySelector("p").firstChild.nodeValue); // Hello!
```

```html
<p>Hello!</p>
```

All text will occur inside of some element and this means that most naturally occurring text nodes will often be those created due to white space included in the source code (carriage returns, tabs, spaces).

I've added an additional line to your output that produces the node type number and you can see that when you click the First Child button, it reports a node type of 3 (text node) as opposed to when you click the Parent Node button, which produces a 1 (element node).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Example</title>
            <meta name="author" content="Adam Freeman"/>
            <meta name="description" content="A simple example"/>
            <style>
                pre {border: medium double black;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <pre id="results"></pre>
            <p id="tblock">
                There are lots of different kinds of fruit - there are over 500 varieties
                of <span id="banana">banana</span> alone. By the time we add the countless
                types of <span id="apple">apples</span>,
                <span="orange">oranges</span="orange">, and other well-known fruit, we are
                faced with thousands of choices. 
            </p>
            <p>
                One of the most interesting aspects of fruit is the variety available in
                each country. I live near London, in an area which is known for
                its apples.
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="parent">Parent</button>
                <button id="child">First Child</button>
                <button id="prev">Prev Sibling</button>
                <button id="next">Next Sibling</button>
            </p>
     
            <script>
                var resultsElem = document.getElementById("results");
                var element = document.body;
                
                var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
                for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                    buttons[i].onclick = handleButtonClick;
                }
                
                processNewElement(element);
    
                function handleButtonClick(e) {
                    if (element.style) {
                        element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    
                    if (e.target.id == "parent" && element != document.body) {
                        element = element.parentNode;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "child" && element.hasChildNodes()) {
                        element = element.firstChild;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "prev" && element.previousSibling) {
                        element = element.previousSibling;
                    } else if (e.target.id == "next" && element.nextSibling) {
                        element = element.nextSibling;
                    }
                    processNewElement(element);
                    if (element.style) {
                        element.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
                    }
                }
                
                function processNewElement(elem) {
                    resultsElem.innerHTML = "Element type: " + elem + "\n";
      resultsElem.innerHTML += "Element id: " + elem.id + "\n";
        resultsElem.innerHTML += "Node type: " + elem.nodeType + "\n";
      resultsElem.innerHTML += "Element text content: " + elem.wholeText + "\n";
                    resultsElem.innerHTML += "Has child nodes: "
                        + elem.hasChildNodes() + "\n";
                    if (elem.previousSibling) {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += ("Prev sibling is: "
                             + elem.previousSibling + "\n");
                    } else {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "No prev sibling\n";
                    }
                    if (elem.nextSibling) {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "Next sibling is: "
                            + elem.nextSibling + "\n";
                    } else {
                        resultsElem.innerHTML += "No next sibling\n";
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the text node you're seeing is the [inter-element whitespace](https://gerardnico.com/web/dom/inter-element_whitespace) between the  tag and the following tags.